# Checking for 2 exact string in a text file using grep

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I'm totally new to shell scripting and I have been reading up on tutorials on how to use different `grep` function. Unfortunately, most of the tutorial usually talk about grepping a certain pattern of the string from the text file.

However, I'm trying to search for two exact strings in the text file.

For example, here is the content of my `BookDB.txt`:

```
Three Little Pigs : Mary Jane
Cinderella : Paul Johnson
```

I tried to get the user input by using the `read` function

```
echo Title :
read Title 

echo Author : 
read Author
```

Next, I used the `grep` command which I gotten help from this [link](//unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206903/match-exact-string-using-grep) to get the string and check if it exist in the `BookDB.txt` file and assign the `echo $?` command output into a variable to display out  some message.

```
grep -w "$Title" BookDB.txt
check1=`echo $?`    

grep -w "$Author" BookDB.txt    
check2=`echo $?`

if [ "$check1" -eq 0 ] && [ "$check2" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo Found
else
    echo Not Found
fi
```

Even though, the user typed `Three` as the `Title` and `Mary` as the `Author`, `echo$?` command still returns 0. Whenever, it returns 0, it displays out the information from the text file which is not required.

Comment: add `-q` option for quiet, if you don't want any info printed.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` searches for words, it wouldn't care if you entered the full name or not, so "Pigs" will match and "Little Pigs" will match too.  It will also return you the same regardless of Author or Title matches (no context).  You can handle it with including the delimiter `:` in the left or right of the entered string.

However, there is a better approach with `awk`

```
$ awk -F' *: *' -v author="Mary Jane" -v title="Three Little Pigs"      \
           '{a=author?author==$2:1; t=title?title==$1:1} t && a' file
```

where you can control whether you want to match both author and title (as given) or either author or title (change `&&` to `||`).  You can provide either values or both and the script will handle it.

Comment: I changed the question for better clarity, i'm actually trying to see if the exact string could be found in the text file.

Comment: add -q option for quiet, if you don't want any info printed and just check the status of match.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, but you need to check that the same line matches both the author and title.  You have to test the whole line with a single `grep`, and you can directly use the return code of `grep` in your `if` statement.

Try this :

```
DB="BookDB.txt"
if
  grep "^[[:space:]]*$Title[[:space:]]*:[[:space:]]*$Author[[:space:]]*$" "$DB"
then
    echo Found
else
    echo Not Found
fi
```

The many `[[:space:]]*` patterns make grep ignore additional spaces.

Add the `-i` option to grep if you want to make the match insensitive to upper/lower case.